# Random Image for 404

Tags: javascript, html, css

To start off I'm terrible at Js and super new at it. I'm trying to make a random image pop up when the site goes to a 404. I can't tell if my website is actually running the code or not because console.log wasn't working. Because of that I took all my CSS and js and put it all into the same HTML file to see if that was the problem (it wasn't) Any help is much appreciated :)

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
  <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/php/ballsdeep1headndnav.php"; ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css" />
  <style>
    .yikes {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .white {
      color: white;
    }

    .cute_block {
      border: blue;
      border: 10px;
      margin: 50px;
    }

    label {
      margin: 10px;
    }

    input {
      margin: 10px;
      color: black;
    }

  </style>
  <title>Yikes.</title>
</head>

<body class="yikes">
  <h1 class="center white">
    <404>
  </h1>
  <div id="getMeme()"></div>
  <p class="white cute_block center">We have no clue how you ended up here</p>
  <form class="white cute_block center">
    <label for="how">How did you get here</label>
    <input type="text" id="how" name="how"><br><br>
    <label for="else">Anything else?</label>
    <input type="text" id="else" name="else"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  function getMeme() {
    var meme = new Array('images/no_more-ico.png', 'images/nothing.png', 'images/phpfiles.png', 'images/sike.png');
    var pp = Math.floor(Math.random() * meme.length);
    document.getElementById("result").onload = '<img src="' + meme[pp] + '" />';
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You've created the function `getMeme()`, but I don't see you calling it anywhere? I also don't really see the question being related to PHP.

Comment: Sorry about the call function, that was in my newest version but not the one I posted, and I also removed the PHP tag. It still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code, you would need to ensure the function `getMeme` is called/invoked. Furthermore, you would need to update the function to modify the `innerHTML` of the element with `id` `result` instead of assigning to it's event handler `onload`.

See demo below:

I've included a `console.log` for debugging purposes on stackoverflow as images shared in the question are not available.

```html
<head>
  <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/php/ballsdeep1headndnav.php"; ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../main.css" />
  <style>
    .yikes {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .white {
      color: white;
    }

    .cute_block {
      border: blue;
      border: 10px;
      margin: 50px;
    }

    label {
      margin: 10px;
    }

    input {
      margin: 10px;
      color: black;
    }

  </style>
  <title>Yikes.</title>
</head>

<body class="yikes">
  <h1 class="center white">
    <404>
  </h1>
  <span id="result"></span>
  <p class="white cute_block center">We have no clue how you ended up here</p>
  <form class="white cute_block center">
    <label for="how">How did you get here</label>
    <input type="text" id="how" name="how"><br><br>
    <label for="else">Anything else?</label>
    <input type="text" id="else" name="else"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-p34f1UUtsS3wqzfto5wAAmdvj+osOnFyQFpp4Ua3gs/ZVWx6oOypYoCJhGGScy+8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  function getMeme() {
    var meme = new Array('images/no_more-ico.png', 'images/nothing.png', 'images/phpfiles.png', 'images/sike.png');
    var pp = Math.floor(Math.random() * meme.length);
    console.log("chose meme",meme[pp]); //line included for debugging purposes on stackoverflow as images shared in question are not available
    //update  `innerHTML` of target element
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = '<img src="' + meme[pp] + '" />';
  }
  //call function to getMeme at the end of the page
  getMeme();
  
</script>
</body>
</html>
```